# Parse Query containsAllObjectsInArray in Swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform

In my Parse `class` "Challenge" i have an `column` "status" which contains a `Number` between 0-5.

When im loading the data from Parse, i only want objects which contain number 1 or 2 in the column "status".

```
query.whereKey("status", containsAllObjectsInArray: [1,2])
```

This gives me a result of 0 Objects.
While this gives me the right answer

```
query.whereKey("status", lessThan: 2)
```

but i dont want to use this line, since i will need different numbers (example only 3 and 5).

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with containedIn :

```
query.whereKey("status", containedIn: [1,2])
```